# Define a name to the posts slug

Tags: posts, slug

I would like to use the url `http://site.com/post/title-of-the-post` for my posts and I've saw in my admin page I have the current url `http://site.com/%slug%/title-of-the-post` obiouvsly incorrect.

How can I define the slug for my default posts?
I'm using various custom post types so I would like to name the default posts simply to `post`, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your permalink structure to custom and use:

```
/post/%postname%/
```

Then when registering your custom post types use something like this:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' => 'something',
    'with_front' => false
),
```

Using `with_front` set to false will make sure that your new custom post types don't share the `/post/` part of your permalink structure

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Structure Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Structure_Tags) for permalink settings in the WordPress Codex.